# PHP forward subdomain to other webpage (via referral url)

Tags: php

I've only used PHP a few times, so I need little help.

I'm looking for a way to read the subdomain the user are visiting.

If they for example visit (*anything*).mysite.com  they will be forwarded to myothersite.com/(*anything*)

Is this possible with php?

I don't have access to https.conf

Update:

Apparently it's my web on a shared server, so when forwarding a subdomain to the domain, it does this c via iframe.

This causes the server uri to be faulty, however, just changing the server_uri to http_referer didn't work.

Anybody got any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can use some header('Location: myothersite.com/monkey'); in combination with checking the referrer header ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])

Comment: which is the server apache?

Comment: I'm on a hosted server, they are running apache 2.22.....

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

The question changed during the investigation, so I won't 'award' myself, but give it to the answer that worked on my start question..

How to redirect VIA REFERRAL from subdomain on one site to other sites subdirectory

This can be used to forward a subdomain(s) to sites running thru iframe.

```
  <?PHP

    $REFERRER = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 


    $domain = substr($REFERRER, strpos($REFERRER, '://')+3); 
    $domain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '/')); 
    // This line will return 'en' of 'en.example.com' 

$subdomain = substr($domain, 0, strpos($domain, '.'));   
    header("Location: https://server2.com)/'.$subdomain");

    ?>
```

Oh one more important thing I discovered, make sure the site don't display anything before calling the header function, that won't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this procedural code and adapte it to your project

```
    $host = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $subdomain = null;
    if(count($host) > 2) //If it has subdomain
    {
            $subdomain = $host[0];
    }
    header('Location: http://myhost.com/'. $subdomain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use virtualhosts(httpd.conf) via apache server. This is a better option than php redirection.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName abc.example.com
  Redirect / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example_folder"
 ServerName example.com
 ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error_log"
 CustomLog "logs/example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm sure your answer are correct, however, I don't have access to the https.conf

Comment: if you have a access to domain name settings change it in the DNS settings change values for the  CNAME records eg xyz.example.com add value as example.com it will redirect in domain level itself

Comment: Yep, you are correct there, however, if one is running a server that needs to forward many subdomains, that are constantly increasing, would be a hard task..